# Python Youtube Audio Downloader using Website

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, download, youtube

So I am writing a simple script to extract links from a Youtube video, and then download the audio from each of the links. Extracting the links I got down using *urllib*, however, *youtube_dl* is being more problematic.

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A"])
```

I have the correct "*ydl_opts*" and everything, but it keeps rasing:

```
DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.
```

Even after Googling this, and installing *ffprobe*, I keep getting this error... and the weird thing is I can import *ffprobe* at the beginning of the program but *youtube_dl* doesn't detect it(?).

So I am trying another idea:
Use a third party website like "*youtube-mp3.org*", get a template link like:

```
"""http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id={1}&ts_create=1451072960&r=MjQuMjEuMTc5LjU2&h2=12c386ccffa12ee7b16dd25078df2558&s=156489""".format(video_link_id)
```

... then formatting it with Youtubes unique video ID, and download it with *urllib.urlopen()*, but that download link generates unique arguments that can't be used with other videos. So is there a way to download from a website **like** that, and/or supply argument like changing the download URL algorithm? Or something to that effect?

Overall objective:

1. Get Youtube video ID
2. Download and convert to mp3 or similar format
3. Play audio within Python

Bonus:

1. Do it as efficiently and quickly as possible (i.e Not downloading entire video, or extra conversion steps)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you a package called [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube).

I have used it and am very pleased with the results. It downloads the video, and after that you can use a library to extract only the audio.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but from the sound of it, I think it'll be a little heavy if it has to download the entire video then convert it. I am trying to do it as fast as possible without using excessive memory. Thanks though!